# Find an estimator of linear regression when errors variance is correlated with one of the K regressors

Tags: least-squares, regression-coefficients, heteroscedasticity, point-estimation

I need to answer to the following problem:

In an heteroschedasticity setting, let $n$ be the index of the n-th statistical unit with $n=1, \dots, N$.

Suppose a multiple linear regression setting with K regressors in which for the N units the errors' variance $\sigma^2$ is proportional to the square of the k-th regressor $x_k$:

$$\sigma^2_n=\sigma^2x^2_{nk}$$

Propose an estimator and show how you would modify the regression model.

What does it mean to propose and estimator? Should I use IV regression? Panel data?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the estimator is supposed to estimate $\sigma^2$ using the data in the observations, so you want to propose some suitable function of the data and the output of the regression model suitably modified

Comment: A constant can be an estimator, so some details will be needed about what characteristics you want your estimator to have. Unbiased? Consistent? Maximum likelihood? And an estimator of what, the coefficients?

Comment: If the goal is to find another point estimator than OLS, GLS would seem like a popular strategy.